# Using Ajax to run a php script every X seconds

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**My project :**

I'm trying to do a captive portal to share the Internet connection but the client have to agree the user agreement first. After that he can have the Internet connection **if he stays on the portal page**.

**Issue :**

My issue is to check if the client is still on my page to provide to him the connection.

For this, I try to add his MAC address as an exception in my iptables every 10 sec because I flush all MAC exception every 15s (except if the @MAC is more than twice, I let one).

**My folder contains :**

index.php (the main page where everything is displayed) and mac.php (where I add the exceptions for @MAC)

**My mac.php :**

```
<?php
$ipAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$macAddr=false;

$arp=`arp -a $ipAddress`;
$lines=explode(" ", $arp);
$macAddr=$lines[3];

echo exec("sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -m mac --mac-source $macAddr -j ACCEPT");
echo exec("sudo /sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -m mac --mac-source $macAddr -j ACCEPT");
?>
```

**I already try to this in my index.php :**

```
<script>
setInterval(
(function () {
    $("#mac").load("mac.php");
}), 10000);
</script>
<div id="mac"></div>
```

and this :

```
    <script>
    setInterval(
    (function () {
        $("#mac").load("mac.php #mac");
    }), 10000);
    </script>

 <div id="mac">
 <?php
    $ipAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $macAddr=false;

    $arp=`arp -a $ipAddress`;
    $lines=explode(" ", $arp);
    $macAddr=$lines[3];

    echo exec("sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -m mac --mac-source $macAddr -j ACCEPT");
    echo exec("sudo /sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -m mac --mac-source $macAddr -j ACCEPT");
    ?>
</div>
```

And I already tried other alternatives like :

- to put the the 2 last lines of mac.php in mac.php called with an argument ($macAddr) and to call mac.php with an argument

The only way that works from now is to refresh the page every 10s. But as you may know, it is not the best way...

I'm working an a Linux system.

Thanks for your help

Comment: define your `script` after `div`

Comment: Or surround the script with `$(document).ready(function() { /* your code */ });` (if you use jQuery)

Comment: you are never executing `$arp='arp -a $ipAddress';` so you are never getting their MAC ADDRESS

Comment: @cmorrissey: he is executing it. Those are backticks around the command, not regular quotes.

Comment: @MilanBabuškov ah you are correct, slightly confusing that he is using that notation and `exec` below

Comment: I tried something else and my issue comes from the interval time :
`setInterval(function(), time_in_millisec);`
Is this correct in JS ? Is it need some configuration on the server to accept this ? Or on the client side ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with :

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    function mac() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            xmlhttp.responseText;
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "mac.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }

    mac();
    setInterval(mac, 10000);
</script>
```

Comment: Good stuff :) - One suggestion - you might want to have a look at something like Node with Socket IO for this kind of stuff. It might be better suited, worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

while true will execute infinite.
mac.php :

```
    <?php
    function checkMac(){
            $ipAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            $macAddr=false;

            $arp=`arp -a $ipAddress`;
            $lines=explode(" ", $arp);
            $macAddr=$lines[3];

            echo exec("sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -m mac --mac-source $macAddr -j ACCEPT");
            echo exec("sudo /sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -m mac --mac-source $macAddr -j ACCEPT");


          }
     ?>
```

all other page where you require to call this page. like ex.

abc.php

```
<?php
require_once('mac.php');
  while(true){
     checkMac();
     sleep(10); // this should halt for 10 seconds for every loop
  } 


?>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Watch out for PHP's script run time limit. PHP will kill your script if it runs too long.

Comment: you can set "set_time_limit" for execution
link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: If I put a "while (true)", I won't be able to cut the Internet connection for the client if he leaves the page. So that why I have to run the mac.php every 10 seconds.

Comment: create one global function in php and call it in those page where you require to check this condition.